# Can AuraEnabled methods be consumed by Off-Platfrom (e.g. Vue or Blazor) frontends?

Tags: controller, integration, aura, rest

Let's say, hypothetically speaking, I already have an Apex class which provides a backend for either an Aura or LWC component.

Now, for some reason, I have an application which is hosted off Salesforce, which I need to interact with Salesforce, working the same properties and functions.

Rather than reinvent the wheel and create another controller (e.g. a REST controller) which would do the same thing, would it be possible to have my application authenticate to Salesforce and submit (presumably REST) requests against the Aura controller?

Or, more precisely, would there be a "safe", "reliable", non-hackish way of doing this where we would not be relying on unpublished implementation details that might change in the future?

And if so, is there any public documentation or example code for doing this?

(Yes, I know I could share code between multiple controllers and there may be good arguments in favour of doing that, but that isn't my question.  Rather, I just want to know exactly if and how I can leverage existing Aura controllers without touching them.)

Comment: @identigral Not really.  I know I could share code between Aura and REST controllers, and there might be good arguments in favour of doing that.  BUT I want to know whether it is possible to leverage the Aura API itself and (if so) how.

Comment: It isn't possible for a number of reasons, security being one of them as the comments in the other answer correctly point out.

Comment: Security might be a reason not to, but it wouldn't necessarily be something which makes it impossible or impractical.  That said, I'd be a little concerned about a security model which assumes a frontend is more trustworthy because it connects using a certain API...  I wouldn't doubt that someone more clever than I could reverse engine the code which lives in the webbrowser to create some new client, although I guess it might also be possible for Sfdc to inject _something_ into it during runtime to ensure the client is authentic...